# Getting x,y pixel coordinates of lat/lon from Mapbox static image

Tags: python, mapbox, geopandas

I have a satellite image using [Mapbox static image API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/static-images/). I am using a bounding box, so I know the coordinates of the four corners of the image.

On this image/map, I have a path defined by a list of [lon, lat] values that is of interest. Mapbox lets me visualize the path when I add a path overlay, which is useful. But I also want to consume the image (without Mapbox's path overlay) in Python to read pixel values of the image along this path. To do this, I need to be able to somehow project the list of [lon, lat] values onto this image's pixel coordinates.

Is there a way to do this without coding the formulas (i.e., using existing Python packages)? Or ,a Mapbox native way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [geopandas](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/) should answer most of your needs, extending `pandas`' `DataFrame` concept to give you the ability to store a list of geometries, and it comes with a lot of tools to deal with the associated [CRS](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/projections.html#coordinate-reference-systems).

Basically, you'll just have to create a `GeoDataFrame` based on your [lat, lon] list, with the proper CRS set, and from there you just convert your data to the CRS of your MapBox image (which seems to be Web Mercator, so EPSG:3857) using the `to_crs()` method, and voilà!

As a side note, you could also use [contextily](https://contextily.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [xyzservices](https://xyzservices.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) to get your background map from MapBox (or any other provider).